# How can I change column names of data.frames within a list with vector of same length in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of length "x" and I want to change a column name of all data.frames within this list using a vector of characters of same length of this list, as described below:

```
a <- data.frame(rep(1:10), letters[1:10])
b <- data.frame(rep(11:20), letters[11:20])
l <- list(a,b)
nm <- c("letters1:10","letters11:20")
```

I want something like:

```
colnames(l[[1]]); colnames(l[[2]])
```

that gives me

```
[1] "rep.1.10."     "letters.1.10."
[1] "rep.11.20."     "letters.11.20."
```

I tried `lapply(l, function(x) colnames(x)[2]<-nm)`
but it returns me a list with nm only and I wanted a list with the original data.frames with updated colnames.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cludgy, but it seems to work (if I've understood the question).

```
lapply(as.list(1:2), function(x){colnames(l[[x]])[2] <- nm[x];l[[x]]})
```

Comment: Thank you! It really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Map( function(x,y){colnames(x)[2] <-y;x},l,nm)
 [[1]]
    rep.1.10. letters1:10
 1          1           a
 2          2           b
 3          3           c
 4          4           d
 5          5           e
 6          6           f
 7          7           g
 8          8           h
 9          9           i
 10        10           j

 [[2]]
    rep.11.20. letters11:20
 1          11            k
 2          12            l
 3          13            m
 4          14            n
 5          15            o
 6          16            p
 7          17            q
 8          18            r
 9          19            s
 10         20            t
```

Comment: Thank you! However I want to change just the second column name.

Comment: `lapply(l,function(x) {colnames(x)[2]=nm[1];x})`

Comment: That just changes the second column name of both data frames to the same thing (i.e., `letters11:20`). Whereas, the second column of the first data frame should be `letters1:10`.

Comment: Try it again. sorry I used 2 instead of 1. Hope that helps. Thank you

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. That names both the second columns the same thing again.

Comment: thank you again. I tried this but it repeats the same value "letters11:20" and I want "letters1:10" on first element of the list and then "letters 11:20" on the second element of the list. It happens what @Lyngbarkr says though.

Comment: ohh sorry I now understand what you mean. I Just logged back in. I will edit my solution in a second.